# Ionic Framework with Crosswalk not working - unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I have installed the ionic framework cordova and I have used the command the below command for setting up crosswalk.

```
npm install ionic
ionic start my_app
cd my_app
ionic browser add crosswalk
ionic run android
```

When I ran the last command line

> ionic run android

The project build is successful. But when it is launched on Android emulator, I got this error

> "unfortunately app has stopped".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried explicitly running `ionic build android` before `ionic run`?

Comment: ya tried but the same error ("unfortunately app has stopped") occurs in emulator

Comment: nope :/ still facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

I tried that ionic crosswalk integration too and failed. It seems unfinished to me. It converts the cordova android platform project to gradle build but there the NDK support is not available yet, so I guess that's where ionic browser add crosswalk fails. Gradle is not able to compile / include the native libraries required for Crosswalk.

The manual way however works like a charm:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html

Section Migrate to Crosswalk